# Who discovered diamagnetism first?

Tags: physics, experimental-physics, electromagnetism

Ferromagnetism is everyday life.

Paramagnetism is not rare.

But diamagnetism is rare and weak.

So, who first discovered diamagnetism? in which material?

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) "Diamagnets were first discovered when Sebald Justinus Brugmans observed in 1778 that bismuth and antimony were repelled by magnetic fields." Do you need more information or a better source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit for discovering diamagnetism is given to different people. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) states that Sebald Justinus Brugmans was the first to discover it, in 1778, when he observed bismuth and antimony being repelled by magnetic fields. Interestingly enough, some sources (e.g. [Kustler (2007)](http://revue.elth.pub.ro/upload/292688art01Gerald.pdf)) instead credit his father, Anton Brugmans, with the discovery. The elder Brugmans was also a scientist, and investigated electricity and magnetism, which may have led to the confusion.

Regardless of which Brugmans deserves credit, a more rigorous treatment of diamagnetism was given in 1845 by Michael Faraday (again, see Kustler for more information), who noted that a magnetic field could cause a piece of glass to rotate. Faraday's work was soon built upon by John Tyndall (see [Jackson (2014)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00033790.2014.929743)).